# Iterate through a for loop using multiple cores in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, bigdata

I have the following code that is currently running like normal Python code:

```
def remove_missing_rows(app_list):
    print("########### Missing row removal ###########")
    missing_rows = []

''' Remove any row that has missing data in the name, id, or description column'''
    for row in app_list:
        if not row[1]:
            missing_rows.append(row)
            continue  # Continue loop to next row. No need to check more columns
        if not row[5]:
            missing_rows.append(row)
            continue  # Continue loop to next row. No need to check more columns
        if not row[4]:
            missing_rows.append(row)

    print("Number of missing entries: " + str(len(missing_rows)))  # 967 with current method

    # Remove the missing_rows from the original data
    app_list = [row for row in app_list if row not in missing_rows]
    return app_list
```

Now, after writing this for a smaller sample I wish to run this on a very large data set. To do this I thought it would be useful to utilise the multiple cores of my computer.

I'm struggling to implement this using the multiprocessing module though. E.g. The idea I have is that Core 1 could work through the first half of the data set, while Core 2 would work through the last half. Etc. And do this in parallel. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this cpu bound?

Comment: app_list is basically a huge list of lists (think a CSV file with 9 columns). I think that's CPU-bound, no? But don't quote me on that.

Comment: huge things are usually RAM bound. but it depends on the type of processing you're doing. I'd check that first.

Comment: I have a lot of methods dealing with the data. But what this specific method does is to look for empty (missing) data in three columns. It does this for every row. So my initial thought was that 2 cores could check the same amount of rows as 1 core but in half the time. Maybe this reasoning is wrong.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the 2 scans through *app_list* (aka the CSV)? You really should just iterate through it and yield rows that pass your criteria. That'd be easier to split too, if need be.

Comment: you could leverage concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor, but first try to make your single thread and single process code as optimized as possible (see @ReutSharabani answer)

Comment: @AMargheriti I've posted an optimization. Didn't check it but the point is that sets are way faster than lists for `contains` operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not cpu bound. Try the code below.

I've used a `set` for very fast (hash-based) `contains` (you use it when you invoke `if row not in missing_rows`, and it's very slow for a long list).

If this is the csv module you're already holding tuples which are hashable so not many changes needed:

```
def remove_missing_rows(app_list):
    print("########### Missing row removal ###########")
    filterfunc = lambda row: not all([row[1], row[4], row[5]])
    missing_rows = set(filter(filterfunc, app_list))

    print("Number of missing entries: " + str(len(missing_rows)))  # 967 with current method

    # Remove the missing_rows from the original data
    # note: should be a lot faster with a set
    app_list = [row for row in app_list if row not in missing_rows]
    return app_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter, to not iterate twice:

```
def remove_missing_rows(app_list):

    filter_func = lambda row: all((row[1], row[4], row[5]))

    return list(filter(filter_func, app_list))
```

But if you are doing data analysis, you probably should have a look into pandas. 
There you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your/csv/data/file', usecols=(1, 4, 5))
df = df.dropna() # remove missing values
```